# Write JSON data at a specific position

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JSON data. I want to put each item in a specific position of a form. Is this possible?

```js
var objs = [{
  "Object1": {
    "ID": 1,
    "type": "input",
    "color": "red",
    "Text": "DARKDRAGON",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "top": "50%",
    "left": "25%",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "150px"
    }
  },
  "Object2": {
    "ID": 2,
    "type": "textarea",
    "color": "cyan",
    "Text": "SPEEDYTIGER",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "top": "50%",
    "left": "25%",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "150px"
    }
  },
  "Object3": {
    "ID": 3,
    "type": "input",
    "color": "blue",
    "Text": "AMyesteriousAdults",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "top": "50%",
    "left": "25%",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "150px"
    }
  },
  "Object4": {
    "ID": 4,
    "type": "button",
    "color": "darkorange",
    "Text": "AMyesteriousDarkSpeed",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "top": "50%",
    "left": "25%",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "150px"
    }
  }
}]

objs.forEach(function(objs) {
  for (var k in objs) {
    if (objs[k] instanceof Object) {
      console.log(objs[k].type);
      var elmn = document.createElement(objs[k].type);
      elmn.textContent = objs[k].Text;
      elmn.style.color = objs[k].color;
      elmn.DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC = objs[k].top;
      document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(elmn);
    } else {
      console.log('Else');
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="ColorArea">
  </div>
  <script src="Main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want like one on left one on bottom or all under each other so it will look well-organized.

Comment: please make it readable

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am trying to organize the data like put them in a certain position like 1 under the other

Comment: it is in my profile it is (How to read an external local JSON file in JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the style properties according to your data object. Make sure your container has `relative` position and the items inside are `absolute`.

If you run the snippet, make sure to click <kbd>Full page</kbd> link or else it will look squished in the preview.

```js
Object.assign(elmn.style, {
  position   : 'absolute',
  color      : formItem.color,
  width      : formItem.width,
  height     : formItem.height,
  top        : formItem.top,
  left       : formItem.left,
  fontFamily : formItem.Font.fontName,
  fontSize   : formItem.Font.font,
});
```

```js
var objs = [{
  "Object1": {
    "ID": 1,
    "type": "input",
    "color": "red",
    "Text": "DARKDRAGON",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "top": "25%",
    "left": "25%",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "150px"
    }
  },
  "Object2": {
    "ID": 2,
    "type": "textarea",
    "color": "cyan",
    "Text": "SPEEDYTIGER",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "top": "50%",
    "left": "50%",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "150px"
    }
  },
  "Object3": {
    "ID": 3,
    "type": "input",
    "color": "blue",
    "Text": "AMyesteriousAdults",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "top": "50%",
    "left": "25%",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "150px"
    }
  },
  "Object4": {
    "ID": 4,
    "type": "button",
    "color": "darkorange",
    "Text": "AMyesteriousDarkSpeed",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "top": "25%",
    "left": "50%",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "150px"
    }
  }
}]

objs.forEach(function(objs) {
  for (var k in objs) {
    if (objs[k] instanceof Object) {
      const formItem = objs[k];
      var elmn = document.createElement(objs[k].type);
      elmn.textContent = formItem.Text;
      
      Object.assign(elmn.style, {
        position: 'absolute',
        color: formItem.color,
        width: formItem.width,
        height: formItem.height,
        top: formItem.top,
        left: formItem.left,
        fontFamily: formItem.Font.fontName,
        fontSize: formItem.Font.font,
      });
      
      document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(elmn);
    } else {
      console.log('Else');
    };
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#ColorArea {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="ColorArea"></div>
```

Comment: i dont want it in  html

Comment: i want it in js property

Comment: @speedy It is in JavaScript... I am not sure why you say it is not.

Comment: ummm let me check

Comment: srry but i mean in my json object there is top and left and i want it to be read by js and drawed

Comment: @speedy I assigned `top` and `left` positioning in the example. You need to make sure the element is positioned `absolute` for this to work.

Comment: how can i do that?     please send me an example for the same code

Comment: @speedy This is not a code-writing service. I just showed you how to apply style via JavaScript. There is nothing I haven't already said that is missing from the example above.

Comment: i tried to put the code but it didn't work can u send it again in a better way

Comment: i want the top and left when i change them they work and change places like what happens i css but i want it in JS property

Comment: can u make it clear like change size and make the code better like readable so i can copy and paste it

Comment: i didn't know how to put the code or where cuz it is a bit messy

Comment: like the new code that u made if u can put it in the edit fiddle and send the link i would apprciate it

Comment: and 1 question if i want to change the top and the left does they change?

Comment: @speedy If you are having issues, I suggest you take a step back and read the official documentation for [**ElementCSSInlineStyle.style**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) on MDN. Also, if you are unsure of how to use `top`, please review [**top**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) (also MDN).

Comment: and if u can make it all under each other it will be better when i change them i can see the changes

Comment: if u can make them all under each other and make them well sized and send them back to me it will be better can u please send it (Well sized and all of the buttons, and text areas , input all under each other and send them to me)!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you need

```
var objs = {
    "Object1": {
        "ID": 1,
        "type": "input",
        "color": "red",
        "Text": "DARKDRAGON",
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "top": "50%",
        "left": "25%",
        "Font": {
            "fontName": "tahoma",
            "font": "150px"
        }
    },
    "Object2": {
        "ID": 2,
        "type": "textarea",
        "color": "cyan",
        "Text": "SPEEDYTIGER",
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "top": "50%",
        "left": "25%",
        "Font": {
            "fontName": "tahoma",
            "font": "150px"
        }
    },
   "Object3": {
        "ID": 3,
        "type": "input",
        "color": "blue",
        "Text": "AMyesteriousAdults",
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "top": "50%",
        "left": "25%",
        "Font": {
            "fontName": "tahoma",
            "font": "150px"
        }
    },
    "Object4": {
        "ID": 4,
        "type": "button",
        "color": "darkorange",
        "Text": "AMyesteriousDarkSpeed",
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "top": "50%",
        "left": "25%",
        "Font": {
            "fontName": "tahoma",
            "font": "150px"
        }
    }
};

var base_node = document.getElementById("ColorArea");
var new_line = document.createElement("br");

Object.values(objs).forEach(function(item) {

  var new_element = document.createElement(item.type);
  new_element.style.display = "block";
  new_element.style.color = item.color;
  new_element.style.width = item.width;
  new_element.style.height = item.height;
  new_element.style.top = item.top;
    new_element.style.left = item.left;
  new_element.value = item.Text;

  base_node.appendChild(new_element);
  base_node.appendChild(new_line);
  
})
```

Comment: i want the top and left when i change them they work and change places like what happens i css but i want it in JS property

Comment: take a look here https://jsbin.com/lutebecogo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this: The elements will be displayed one below the other.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #ColorArea {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="ColorArea">
    </div>
    <script src="Main.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

```
var objs = [{
    "Object1": {
        "ID": 1,
        "type": "input",
        "color": "red",
        "Text": "DARKDRAGON",
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "top": "50%",
        "left": "25%",
        "Font": {
            "fontName": "tahoma",
            "font": "150px"
        }
    },
    "Object2": {
        "ID": 2,
        "type": "textarea",
        "color": "cyan",
        "Text": "SPEEDYTIGER",
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "top": "50%",
        "left": "25%",
        "Font": {
            "fontName": "tahoma",
            "font": "150px"
        }
    },
    "Object3": {
        "ID": 3,
        "type": "input",
        "color": "blue",
        "Text": "AMyesteriousAdults",
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "top": "50%",
        "left": "25%",
        "Font": {
            "fontName": "tahoma",
            "font": "150px"
        }
    },
    "Object4": {
        "ID": 4,
        "type": "button",
        "color": "darkorange",
        "Text": "AMyesteriousDarkSpeed",
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "top": "50%",
        "left": "25%",
        "Font": {
            "fontName": "tahoma",
            "font": "150px"
        }
    }
}]

objs.forEach(function (objs) {
    for (var k in objs) {
        if (objs[k] instanceof Object) {
            var elmn = document.createElement(objs[k].type);
            elmn.textContent = objs[k].Text;
            elmn.style.color = objs[k].color;
            elmn.style.margin = '10px';
            elmn.style['word-break'] = 'break-word';
            elmn.style.width = objs[k].width;
            elmn.style.height = objs[k].height;
            document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(elmn);
        } else {
            console.log('Else');
        };
    }
});
```

- If you want to set the value for an input element, you can add an additional check like

```
if(objs[k].type == 'input') {
   elmn.value = objs[k].Text;
} else {
   elmn.textContent = objs[k].Text;
}
```

Comment: i dont want html i want a js property

Comment: i want the top and left when i change them they work and change places like what happens i css but i want it in JS property